# How to translate views infinite scroll Loading message

Tags: 7, views

I have an Arabic website and I have views infinite scroll module to allow ajax paging.

[image]

I want to translate `Loading the next set of posts...`. I have tried to search for it in the translate interface, but I could not find it. I tried to import its *.po file from [this link](https://localize.drupal.org/translate/downloads?project=views_infinite_scroll) but also I could not find it. I have tried to search among the module `views_infinite_scroll` files, for that string to change it from the source, but also I could not find.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [webpal pinteros](http://demo.weebpal.com/pinteros) theme, and it has its own `js/views_infinite_scroll.js` file, in-which the message could be translated. However, this solution is not suitable for multiple languages sites.